# Is $Tf=x_0+\int_0^tf(t)(1-f)\,dt$ a Lipschitz function?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, functional-equations

Consider the Banach space $C[0,1]$ with the uniform norm and the operator given by $(T(f))x=x_0+\int_0^xf(t)(1-f(t))\,dt$ for $x\in[0,1]$ and $x_0\geq0$.

I want to show that there is a number $0<L<1$ sucht that $|(Tf-Tg)(x)|\le L\lVert f-g\rVert_{\infty}$ for $f,g\in C[0,1]$.

I have done the following:

$|(Tf-Tg)(x)|=|\int_0^xf(t)(1-f(t)) - g(t)(1-g(t))\,dt|$,

I am stuck at this point, since I do not know how to find a good estimate for the integrand.

Can someone help?

Comment: Let $f=C$ be constant for some large positive constant. Let $g=0$. Then $Tf-Tg = C(1-C)x$. But $|Tf-Tg|=C(C-1)x$. So $C(C-1)x=|Tf-Tg| \le L\|f-g\|=LC$ cannot hold for all $0 \le x \le 1$ for large enough $C$.

Comment: FYI,  the requirement you are looking for is stronger than Lipschitz,  it's called a 'contraction'.   Lipschitz would require only $L>0$,  not also $L<1$

Answer (score 0):

What you want to show is not true.

To see this, note that this would imply (by taking $g \equiv 0$) that $|Tf(x)|$ grows at most linearly in $f$. But since the integrand is **quadratic** in $f$, it is easy to see that this cannot hold (take $f \equiv c$ for large $c$).